# Ошибка с Beautiful Soup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Пока в самом начале самообучения, по книге , поэтому заранее прошу прощения за "своеобразное" объяснение и ошибки.

В книге одно из практических заданий связано с модулем Beautiful Soup. Установил его через консоль, установка завершилась успешно.
Собственно сама практика выглядит так:

```
import bs4 
exampleFile = open('example.html')
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(exampleFile.read())
elem = exampleSoup.select('#author')
type(elem)
```

При вызове пишет ошибку -

```
The code that caused this warning is on line 3 of the file C:\Python\t.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.
```

Из сообщения понял + прочел на англоязычных форумах (с английским вери бэд), что проблему должна исправить запись -

```
('html.parser)
```

Добавил ее в строку - exampleFile = open('example.html')
Появилась другая:

```
exampleFile = open('example.html', 'html.parser')
ValueError: invalid mode: 'html.parser'
```

Пока жду ответа, решил продолжить и в следующем задании:

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4

print('Гуглим...')
res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
```

Опять та же ошибка, что и в первом случае, но тут добавив

```
html.parser - в строку soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
```

Ошибка пропадает. Объясните в чем проблема и разница, между двумя этими ситуациями. Если это как-то поможет использую Sublime Text 3, запускаю через командную строку (cmd), Beautiful Soup 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1

Да, Вы правильно поняли, что надо добавить `html.parser`, но добавили Вы это, почему-то, не в конструктор `BeautifulSoup`, а в функцию `open` (зачем?).

> ```py
> exampleFile = open('example.html', 'html.parser')
> ValueError: invalid mode: 'html.parser'
> ```

Ошибка говорит о том, что выбран неправильный режим для открытия файла. Появляется она из-за того, что нет режима `html.parser` для открытия файла. Файлы можно открывать на чтение, запись, дозапись и т.д. Подробнее смотреть в [документации функции open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

---

## 2

Тут Вы сделали правильно. `BeautifulSoup` в качестве второго аргумента ожидает, какой парсер ему использовать. Добавляя `html.parser` в конструктор `BeautifulSoup` Вы говорите, что хотите использовать встроенный в `Python` парсер. Какие есть ещё парсеры можно посмотреть [тут](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

---

### P.S.

Файлы надо закрывать после работы с ними. `exampleFile.close()`, либо пользоваться контекстным менеджером

```py
with open('example.html') as exampleFile:
    # Do some stuff
```

После выхода из `with` файл закроется автоматически.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, вроде уяснил. Отсюда вытекает следующий вопрос, при выполнении кода (уже исправленного, по вашим рекомендациям), напомню использую Sublime 3 и cmd, экран cmd пустой, то есть по факту ничего не происходит, я так понимаю это по причине того, что в книге используется IDLE, как мне исправить это положение? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: То есть какие другие варианты можно использовать, для выполнения кода? Так будет точнее поставить вопрос.

Comment: @АртемБабкин А что Вы ожидаете вместо пустого экрана? Второй комментарий вообще ничего не уточнил :)

Comment: Если я правильно понял второй комментарий, то пользоваться можно хоть чем. `IDLE`, `cmd`, `PyCharm` - неважно. Лично я пользуюсь `cmd`.